resolve recurrence $a_n=a_{n-1}+3a_{n-3}$
Hy all
I want to try to find the solution for the recurrence $a_n=a_{n-1}+3a_{n-3}$. If i take the equation associate to it, then i have  $x^3-x^2+3=0$. But in this case, i have just one real root and two complex root. So i was thinking in a solution of type $\alpha r_1^n+\beta r_2^n +\gamma r_3^n$ with $r_i$ their root associates, but i do not believe in my argument, is weird for me.
The other hand, i try to use telescopic sum. I mean, $a_n=a_{n-1}+3a_{n-3}$ then
$a_n-a_{n-1}=3a_{n-3}$ then for $N$ large,  $\sum_{i=1}^{N}a_i-a_{i-1}=3\sum_{i=1}^{N}a_{i-3}$. The left side of the last equality is $a_N-a_0$ and the right side $3a_{-1} +3a_{-2}+3a_0+ 3a_1+\ldots 3a_{N-3}$ which implies that
$a_N= 3a_{-1} +3a_{-2}+4a_0+ 3a_1+\ldots 3a_{N-3}$ but what is tell me?
I did other manipulations as divide both sides for terms $a_m$ but i am stuck. Please, can you help me with hints. I do not need a specific solution, i need some approximation because i need to resolve the running time for some algorithm.
Thank you

Why is it a problem if there are complex roots?  Binet's formula for the Fibonacci sequence can be seen as coming from the approach you outline in your first paragraph, where the characteristic polynomial has irrational roots.  The irrational bits all cancel out, however, in the end.  Why wouldn't something similar happen here?

Thank you for the feedback. so maybe i just was scared about manipulating complex number because i did not think that in some place could be cancel some terms and finally it has power of real numbers. But my attempt is well, right?

Did you mean $x^3-x^2\color{red}-3=0$?

If $r_2$ and $r_3=\overline{r_2}$ are the complex zeros, all you need to do is to require $\gamma=\overline{\beta}$. All real, now! So to get all the real valued solutions let $\alpha$ be any real number, $\beta$ can be any complex number, but you need to set $\gamma=\overline{\beta}$.

@JyrkiLahtonen thank you, now i got it and appreciate your comment. Best regards

The Short Version
The imaginary components will all cancel out.
The Long Version
The "usual" line of attack here is to make the ansatz that $a_n$ is some kind of exponential expression, i.e. that $a_n = r^n$ for some $r$.  If this is the case, then
$$ a_n  = a_{n-1} + 3a_{n-3} $$
implies that
$$ r^n = r^{n-1} + 3r^{n-3} \implies r^3 = r^2 + 3, $$
where it implication follows by canceling out a factor of $r^{n-3}$ from both side of the equation.  The roots are given, numerically, by
$$r_1\approx 1.8637, \quad
 r_2\approx -0.43185 - 1.19298 i
 \quad\text{and}\quad
 r_3\approx -0.43185 + 1.19298 i. $$
The recurrence relation is linear, which means that linear combinations of solutions will also be solutions.  Hence the most general solution is a linear combination of these three particular solutions.  That is, the most general closed form is
$$ a_n = \alpha r_1^n + \beta r_2^n + \gamma r_3^n, $$
where $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ are some as-yet undetermined coefficients.
Since the first several terms are not given, the closed form expression of the general term is going to depend on those terms.  However, assuming that $a_1$, $a_2$, and $a_3$ are known, then
$$ \begin{cases}
a_1 = \alpha + \beta + \gamma \\
a_2 = \alpha r_1 + \beta r_2 + \gamma r_3 \\
a_3 = \alpha r_1^2 + \beta r_2^2 + \gamma r_3^2. \end{cases}$$
This is a system of three linear equations in three variables (the variables are $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$—everything else is a constant).  Solving the system for the unknowns is perhaps a little tedious (particularly considering that the values of the $r_i$ are kind of ugly), but completely doable, particularly if you are using a computer.
Finally, assuming that $a_1$, $a_2$, and $a_3$ are pure real numbers, so the values found for $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ must all be such that the imaginary components all cancel out in each line of the system above.  From this, it will follow that the imaginary components of the various terms in
$$ a_n = \alpha r_1^n + \beta r_2^n + \gamma r_3^n$$
will also cancel out.  This can be shown in a fairly straight-forward inductive manner by recalling that $a_n$ of this form will satisfy the recurrence relation
$$ a_n = a_{n-1} + 3 a_{n-3}. $$
Since $a_1$ and $a_3$ are real, it follows that $a_4$ is real.  Then $a_2$ and $a_4$ are real, so $a_5$ must be real.  And so on.

Assumption $a_1, a_2, a_3$ are real is not in the OP.  Is this your addition?

The real root is nice $$\frac{1}{3} \left(1+2 \cosh
\left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh ^{-1}\left(\frac{83}{2}\right)\right )\right)$$

@GEdgar It is implicit in the question---the asker seems to be confused by the existence of complex solutions. But I did try to make this assumption explicit in my answer.

Assuming that sequence of yours starts at $n=1$ it is easy to see that
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a_n\\
a_{n-1}\\
a_{n-2}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 3\\
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{n-1}\\
a_{n-2}\\
a_{n-3}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
for all $n\geq 4$, and so by induction
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a_n\\
a_{n-1}\\
a_{n-2}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 3\\
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}^{n-3}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_3\\
a_2\\
a_1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
for all $n\geq 4$.
Now, the matrix
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 3\\
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
is diagonalizable over the complex numbers, because it has $3$ distinct eigenvalues. At least of them is necessarily real, and by Wolfram Alpha it's the only real one and the other two are complex and each other's conjugates. From there, it's not too hard to calculate $A^n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, and so you should end up with a closed form for $a_n$, if that's what you wanted.

thank you for your solution, i like it.

Here's an approximate clue of why it gets too messy,
$$a_n=a_{n-1}+3a_{n-3}\underset{n\to n+3}\implies a_{n+3}=a_{n+2}+3a_{n}$$
$$Q(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n+3}x^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n+2}x^n+3\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^n$$
$$Q(x)=\frac{a_0+x(a_1-a_0)+x^2(a_2-a_1)}{1-x-3x^3}\implies \cdots$$
Trying to partial fraction the above expression leads to a mess and you can see the general solution here

There is nothing wrong with using complex numbers. The imaginary parts will cancel out, and leave only real parts.

The complex numbers won't cancel out. Real numbers are also complex numbers. You should say "The imaginary parts will cancel out ..."

@jjagmath Thanks for the catch! I'll fix it

Thank you all. This space is not just for smart people, i believe that we can ask all that confuse us and do not have wrong comments of superiority.   Best!
